# BIRT Report chart with aggregated values

Tags: report, aggregation, pie-chart, birt

Im kind of new to this BIRT reporting thing, so my issue might be easy to solve (sorry if so). I made some research and could not find anything helpfull, so I hope anyone got an idea. I'm using BIRT version 4.8.
I have a report which has tons of analysis (from a lab) of different products.
For each product, there are different limits. I get those informations (analysis and limits) form a database (obviously).
Now with all this data, there is a lot of stuff going on within the report. Highlights, different styles, **aggregations** (summary in the heard area of the report).

Things like:

- how many analyzis do I have,
- how many times is the maximum exceeded or below the lower limit
- how many analyzis got only one error, two, three and more than three errors etc.

In the end, I have report looking like this (with many more lines)
[image: example analyzis]

So far so good.
Now I want do make a chart with the data from the head of the report. I want a pie chart like this (example made in ms excel)

[image: pie example]

How do i say within that chart "the pie is 'Total of E'. now add 'No Errors' and 'One Error' and 'Two Error' etc. into my pie, each with a different color"?
[image: BIRT pie chart]

I have access to those aggregations from the head, but I dont know how to add them into the pie chart.
Any ideas would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm. I rewrote my SQL so that all my pie chart values are in one row now (it cost me some 'complex' CASE WHEN THEN conditions within the SQL) but that did the job. So for me, the issue is solved. For others that need some help in this issue in general, any advice would be appreciated.